# Facebook open graph image without meta og:image

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I found sites which are using like button to specific images from galleries and when you like them on facebook they display proper image buth without even using og meta tags???

How they are doing this???

Here is example:

http://www.subotica.com/slike/album-62834-omega-disco-subota-vece/

Try to like any picture and try to debug them on facebook debuger and you will see that there are no meta tags but crawled picture is proper!

Answer (score 0):

They are using the old sharer.php endpoint.

```
http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=URLENCODED_URL_TO_PHOTO
```

That endpoint is officially unsupported. For the moment it still works, but it could be removed at any time. You can accomplish something similar using the [Feed Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/) or the proper og:meta tags.

Comment: i thing you miss understood question! I know for sharer.php but that is not that they are doing, they are using like button but without og:meta tags. I found one difference in their like button and that is url which have some parameters -

Comment: for the example when i like som image on http://www.subotica.com/slike/album-62834-omega-disco-subota in facebook i will get link http://www.subotica.com/slike/album-62834-omega-disco-subota-vece/1/869735/?fb_action_ids=3398858701274&fb_action_types=og.likes&fb_source=timeline_og&action_object_map=%7B%223398858701274%22%3A10151143577342938%7D&action_type_map=%7B%223398858701274%22%3A%22og.likes%22%7D&action_ref_map=%5B%5D, maybe that parameters are telling facebook which image to use in open graph but i could not found any documentation about it.